# Remove students' grades for dates containing the least number of different digits

Tags: c, structure

> Write an `int digit_in_date()` function that receives an array of grades. For all students who have a total of 30 or more ECTS credits in the courses they have passed (have a minimal grade 6 of max 10), it is necessary to remove from the array those grades whose date contains the least number of different digits. E.g. the date 2/20/2020 contains only two different digits (2 and 0). If they have several grades whose dates have the same (smallest) number of digits, all such grades should be removed.
>
> You can find out that the grades belong to the same student based on the first and last name (assume that if two students have the same first and last name, then they are the same student). Assume that the data is valid (valid dates, valid grades, ECTS credits are not negative, etc.)
>
> It is not allowed to use auxiliary strings and it is important to implement structures.

I can't seem to figure out a more efficient way to do this, and the code I have written doesn't give me the expected output for all of my inputs. I have tried different thing but end up with making my program crash or it is taking too long to execute. Here is what I have done so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Date {
    int day, month, year;
};

struct Course {
    int id;
    char name[100];
    double ects;
};

struct Grade {
    char fullname[100];
    int grade;
    struct Course course;
    struct Date date;
};

int count_different_digits(int number) {
    int digits[10] = {0};
    while (number > 0) {
        digits[number % 10]++;
        number /= 10;
    }

    int different_digits_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (digits[i] > 0) {
            different_digits_count++;
        }
    }

    return different_digits_count;
}

int digits_in_date(struct Grade grades[], int number_of_grades) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_grades; i++) {
        if (grades[i].grade >= 6) {
            double total_ects = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < number_of_grades; j++) {
                if (strcmp(grades[i].fullname, grades[j].fullname) == 0) {
                    total_ects += grades[j].course.ects;
                }
            }

            if (total_ects >= 30) {
                int current_date_digits = count_different_digits(grades[i].date.day) +
                                           count_different_digits(grades[i].date.month) +
                                           count_different_digits(grades[i].date.year);

                for (int j = 0; j < number_of_grades; j++) {
                    if (strcmp(grades[i].fullname, grades[j].fullname) == 0 && j != i) {
                        int date_digits = count_different_digits(grades[j].date.day) +
                                          count_different_digits(grades[j].date.month) +
                                          count_different_digits(grades[j].date.year);

                        if (date_digits < current_date_digits) {
                            for (int k = j; k < number_of_grades - 1; k++) {
                                grades[k] = grades[k + 1];
                            }
                            number_of_grades--;
                            j--;  // Adjust the loop index after removal
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return number_of_grades;
}

int main() {
    int number_of_grades;
    printf("Enter the number of grades: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_grades);

    struct Grade *grades = (struct Grade *)malloc(number_of_grades * sizeof(struct Grade));

    printf("Enter grades:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_grades; i++) {
        printf("Grade %d:\n", i + 1);
        printf("Full name: ");
        scanf("%s", grades[i].fullname);
        printf("Grade: ");
        scanf("%d", &grades[i].grade);
        printf("Course name: ");
        scanf("%s", grades[i].course.name);
        printf("ECTS: ");
        scanf("%lf", &grades[i].course.ects);
        printf("Date (day month year): ");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &grades[i].date.day, &grades[i].date.month, &grades[i].date.year);
    }

    digits_in_date(grades, number_of_grades);

    printf("\nGrades after filtering:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_grades; i++) {
        printf("%s - %s - %.1f ECTS - %d.%d.%d\n", grades[i].fullname, grades[i].course.name,
               grades[i].course.ects, grades[i].date.day, grades[i].date.month, grades[i].date.year);
    }

    free(grades);

    return 0;
}
```

##### Test case 1 (good output)

###### Input:

```
struct Grade array[3] = {
    { "Mujo Suljic", 10, { 1, "Introduction to Programming", 25}, { 19, 1, 2020 } },
    { "Fata Fatic", 8, { 1, "Introduction to Programming", 25}, { 19, 1, 2020 } },
    { "Mujo Suljic", 7, { 2, "Engineering Physics 1", 10}, { 11, 1, 2020 } }
};

int size = digits_in_date(array, 3);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%s %s\n", array[i].fullname, array[i].course.name);
```

###### Expected output:

```
Mujo Suljic Intro to programming
Fata Fatic Intro to programming
```

###### My output:

```
Mujo Suljic Intro to programming
Fata Fatic Intro to programming
```

##### Failed test case example:

###### Input:

```
struct Grade array[6] = {
    { "Mujo Suljic", 10, { 1, "Introduction to Programming", 25}, { 20, 2, 2020 } },
    { "Pero Peric", 6, { 5, "Fundamentals of Electrical Engineering", 25}, { 20, 2, 2020 } },
    { "Fata Fatic", 8, { 1, "Introduction to Programming", 25}, { 19, 1, 2020 } },
    { "Mujo Suljic", 5, { 2, "Engineering Physics 1", 10}, { 11, 1, 2020 } },
    { "Mujo Suljic", 10, { 3, "Engineering Mathematics 1", 4}, { 20, 1, 2020 } },
    { "Fata Fatic", 8, { 4, "Engineering Mathematics 1", 25}, { 19, 1, 2020 } }
};

int size = digits_in_date(array, 6);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%s %s %g\n", array[i].fullname, array[i].course.name, array[i].course.ects);
```

###### Expected output:

```
Mujo Suljic Introduction to Programming 25
Pero Peric Fundamentals of Electrical Engineering 25
Mujo Suljic Engineering Physics 1 10
Mujo Suljic Engineering Mathematics 1 4
```

###### My output:

```
Mujo Suljic Introduction to Programming 25
Pero Peric Fundamentals of Electrical Engineering 25
Fata Fatic Introduction to Programming 25
Mujo Suljic Engineering Physics 1 10
Mujo Suljic Engineering Mathematics 1 4
Fata Fatic Engineering Mathematics 1 25
```

Comment: Instead of removing strings, why not don't adding them in the first place? Either use a condition in the printing loop that omit the printing; Or do two passes over the data, first to collect the information you need, and the second to do the actual printing.

Comment: You said `2/20/2020` only contains two different digits, but it you process day, month, year individually and add them up you'll get more than that. I think the `count_different_digits` function should accept a `Date` structure and process all three members as part of the same digit count.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < number_of_grades; i++) { ... number_of_grades--; ... }` That's almost never a good idea. Also, `digits_in_date` seems to be doing to much for a single function and not quite what its name suggests.

Comment: Function `digits_in_date()` does not compute the number of different digits in the date. It computes it for the day, the month and the year of the date, and adds them. So your example 2/20/2020 will give 5 or 6, depending on whether you counted a leading 0 of the day – not the 2 that you say it should be.

Comment: ...and note that your `while (number > 0) { digits[number % 10]++; number /= 10; }` will tell you that `0` has `0` digits, whereas it has `1` digit.